# Manifest in Android library

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a question about Android libraries. Let's say I have got in my library kind of file management. My app needs the `FileProvider`. I get the authorities from app package name. And the question is: Is it okay to give library manifest open for the user and let them change things in there or just say to the user: "Hey, if you want to enable this part of the library which needs file management, go to your app manifest and add `<provider>` there." ?

Currently my `<provider>` looks like this and it is in **app manifest**:

```
<provider android:authorities="com.myPackage.name.FileProvider"
          android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
          android:exported="false"
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
               android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

I consider moving it to the **library manifest** to make configuration easier for the user. But the thing is that I have no idea if making library manifest open is either a good idea or not.

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a correct answer because it depends on your projects requirements and design.

I would let the user define it if it is optional feature for library. Also you are giving your own package as authorities which corrupts development if user wants to use or share same provider with his/her other applications.

But if is static implementation like activity declaration, you don't even need to think about it. Just put your own manifest.

Good luck

Emre

Comment: Now in user app manifest, when he create provider himself there he puts his package name. The library gets it by context. Is that okey? What do you think?

Comment: When he puts his package name, folder is being created under that package which is more meaningful. Its means ownerships. External accessors which is maybe Camera application that opened for capturing a image is going to save the file under that package. If the user wants access it, he dont have to deal with permissions.

Comment: So in short: it is always better to let chose the user how the provider is defined because he knows exactly know how and where it will be doing things. Am I right?

Comment: It depends.. If its need to unique let the user define it. Think about 2 application which uses same library written by you, they are going share same provider or not? You are the one gonna say whats gonna be happen.

This is an example taken by facebook. User defines it because it depends applications. Applications uses Facebook SDK shouldnt share same provider for their implementation. Hope it gives you an answer.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/current/facebook/com/facebook/facebookcontentprovider.html/

Comment: Yeah, the reason I asked this question as I tried to build another app using my library and there was a provider error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to move your provider to the library manifest, because all manifests will merge into one (you can see it in bottom `Merged Manifest` tab in your main `AndroidManifest.xml`)